# Как скрыть часть url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

Как можно преобразовать такой url `http://sitename.ru/katalog/nazvaniekategorii/`
в такой: `http://sitename.ru/nazvaniekategorii/` ?
т.е. нужно вырезать `katalog` из всех url

**P.S.**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/katalog/(.*)
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: вам в какую сторону надо решить задачу? чтобы по ссылке 2 открывалось содержимое ссылки1? Или чтобы все ссылки вида 1 в контенте страницы заменились на ссылки 2 ?

Comment: @teran, чтобы по ссылке `http://sitename.ru/nazvaniekategorii/` открывались страницы `http://sitename.ru/katalog/nazvaniekategorii/`, но чтобы url оставался `http://sitename.ru/nazvaniekategorii/`

Comment: а ваше `nazvaniekategorii` может быть любым словом, или все же `/contacts` не стоит переносить в `katalog/contacts` ?

Comment: @teran, нет, только категории и название категории может быть такое:  `/nazvaniekategorii/subkategoriya`

Comment: нужно было это сразу в вопрос добавить, не знал, что возникнет доп вопросы

Comment: У вас какой сервер стоит `nginx`, `apache` или какой то другой? что вы используете в качестве бэка `cms` или фрейворк.

Comment: apache, opencart, в метках вроде это есть, т.е. .htaccess и opencart

Comment: Ясно, просто вопрос похож на сделайте за меня, и ответ краток, меняете url в cms и делаете редирект с `^/katalog/(.*)` на `/$1` и все

Comment: @Naumov, добавил в вопрос, правильно?

Comment: @Naumov, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно создать правило?